# android studio - opening files from multiple projects

Tags: user-interface, ide, android-studio

is there anyway to open file from multiple project like the eclipse does?!

I am learning android app developing and I use my older projects as my own coding reference (to master em) a lot. previously  I used to do such a thing with ecplispe with ease but in android studio I havent found such an option like project explorer as ecplipse's.
is there such a project explorer thing in android studio?

tnx in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1) Open the older project while new one is open and choose (New Window) when prompted. See [this help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/opening-multiple-projects.html) for more information on using multiple projects/windows (the help is for IntelliJ IDEA, but it works the same in Android Studio).

2) Drag and drop the file you want to view into the window and it will open in it's own tab.

The first option would be best suited if you want to refer to many files in the older project and the second if you just want to quickly view something in one file.